NiceMatrix Package: Dots outside brackets
I am trying to create a simple diagonal matrix with dots along the diagonal, except in the center, where there is a character. The command \Ddots seems to exist for this exact purpose. However, when I implement it, the dots spill out beyond the brackets at the corners. I tried using the [margin=x] command, which improves it slightly, but the dots are no longer truly diagonal to the brackets. And, the matrix becomes unnecessarily wide, as the margin adjusts space in the left and right directions only.
I didn’t see anything in the docs that would address this, but maybe I missed something. I’d appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}

% Default
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        \Ddots &   &        \\
               & x &        \\
               &   & \Ddots 
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

% With Margin
\begin{equation}
B = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin=5pt]
        \Ddots &   &        \\
               & x &        \\
               &   & \Ddots 
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}




With TeX and LaTeX, the exact size and shape of the delimiters depends on the mathematical font.
With your example (which uses Libertinus Math), here is an adjustment of the dotted line with the key shorten-start and shorten-end.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        \Ddots[shorten-start=8pt] &   &        \\
               & x &        \\
               &   & \Ddots[shorten-end=8pt] 
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}



Perfect! I totally missed the custom section of that chapter in the docs. Thank you for pointing that out! I also realized that you are the author of the package. I discovered it not too long ago and have been using it extensively these days. Thank you for sharing. it. I appreciate it!
